# SOQL To Get Opportunity, Account and Contact from one query to Opportunity Object

Tags: soql, opportunity, account, contact, accountcontactrelation

I'm wondering if it is possible to query the Opportunities object and return associated Account and Contact data.

I so far have:

```sql
SELECT Opportunity.Id, 
Opportunity.AccountId, 
Opportunity.Owner.Name, 
Account.Company_Division__c, 
Account.Name, 
Account.BillingStreet, 
Account.BillingCity, 
Account.BillingState, 
Account.BillingPostalCode,     
Account.Phone, 
Account.Fax
FROM Opportunity
```

But I can't figure out the syntax to get the Contacts that are associated with the Account.

I know it has something to do with the AccountContactRelations object, but I can't seem to get there from the Opportunity object.

** This question is NOT looking for the OpportunityContactRole, but rather contacts associated with an Account. **

P.S.: The code I'm working with will take hours to fix if I have to change the `FROM Opportunity` part of this query. I would greatly prefer to not change that if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this from a single SOQL query using `FROM Opportunity`. You'll either need a second query (and some additional processing) or to switch your query to be on `Account` instead.

SOQL makes it simple (though tedious) to traverse up a relationship hierarchy, but really limits what we can do to query *down* a relationship hierarchy. We can only traverse down one level, and only from the object that we're querying in the `FROM` clause.

What you're suggesting would require us to be able to query up a relationship (Opportunity -> Account) and then down from Account (Account -> AccountContactRelation if you have the *allow contacts to be related to multiple accounts* feature enabled, Account -> Contact otherwise), which isn't possible.

A second query, if you can afford to use another, would probably be the fastest way around this.

If your code is relying on being able to use simple dot-notation to traverse from Opp -> Account -> AccountContactRelation/Contact, then there's not going to be a way for you to avoid rewriting that.

Comment: Great info, thanks for the response. I'll have to figure out the SOQL to get the Contacts given an AccountId then. Shouldn't be too hard.